# Sqlite for Windows Runtime and the Designer

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013

I came to a point where I do not find any solution. I am trying to get data from an SQLite Table, which works and the table is copied at first run. But I need to reference the "SQLite for Windows Runtime Extension". But this Extension only works on a ARM Build Process.

But if I want to place my UserControl elements, which get their input from my DB-Wrapper I do not get the Designer to work, because in ARM-Build-Mode the Designer isn't available and in the "Any-CPU"-Mode I get exceptions saying that my UserControl Views could not be found in the Namespace and the SQLite lib does not seem to work on x86/x64.

Has anybody any hints for me?

Ok Figured out another strange behaviour, if I select Any-CPU my VeriableGridView is not found in the Namespace, but if I select ARM-Archtecture it is found...

Comment: looks like the sqlite extension should work on x86, since the designer requires x86 or anycpu I'd suggest trying to get an x86 build to work then see if the designer can work

Comment: do you have any hint for me which sqlite lib i should use? Now its named this way "SQLite.WinRT81, Version=3.8.2"

Comment: "this Extension only works on a ARM Build Process": no, it works fine on x86 and x64 too

Comment: You need to create 3 separate build configurations for ARM, x86 and x64 (you can do that in Build > Configuration manager)